# Starting an application from a script without having a hanging terminal

Tags: shell-script, usability

Good evening!

I'm trying to run an electron application on my PopOS 22.04 machine. It throws an error such as:

```
[Majsoul_Plus][ERROR] gpu-process-crashed, killed: false
[Majsoul_Plus][ERROR] gpu-process-crashed, killed: false
[19781:0624/031622.888875:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(986)] The display compositor is frequently crashing. Goodbye.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

After some research, I figured out that I need to run it with the `--no-sandbox` argument which works fine. I then wanted something that I can run the application with less effort and later add it to the quick launch menu (the one that activates when pressing the windows key). So  I put together this little script, in the same directory:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
./majsoul-plus --no-sandbox
```

Which does what its supposed to do! However, I would like to not have the hanging terminal in the background. I tried `nohup ./majsoul-plus --no-sandbox &` and combinations but it no longer executes. I would also like to incorporate this into a .desktop file to add it to my quick access menu. This one also refuses to execute properly, even in the simple working variant.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not in a position to be able to test this today, but you should be able to use `screen` or `tmux` to kick off an independent terminal session

```
#!/bin/sh
screen -md -S majsoul "$HOME/majsoul-plus" --no-sandbox
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want it to do. Thank you very much.